# Ceiling fan bulbs repeatedly fail

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture

My Ceiling fan light in my bedroom keeps going out.  I changed the bulb and it worked for a few days and went out again.  I changed it again and days later it went out again.  The ceiling fan itself runs fine so I am not sure if I need to call an electrician or go from a 40W to a 60W bulb.

Comment: Are you buying the correct voltage bulbs?

Comment: Is there vibration in the fan? What type of bulb are you using?  Is there a dimmer controlling the light.

Comment: The wattage of a bulb generally isn't related to its durability. Also, there's no need to YELL. :)

Comment: Have you tried using a light bulb designed for use in a ceiling fan?

Comment: i got the same kind of bulb that i was instructed to buy. i talked to an electrician and he said to change the bulb but when i did it did the same thing.

Comment: the  ceiling fan has vibration and works fine. there seems to be nothing wrong with the fan.

Comment: the bulb that i am using is a 40w crystal clear 305 lumens by GE

Comment: If the fan causes the bulb to vibrate, you'll want to follow Ed Beal's advice and get "*heavy duty*" bulbs.

Comment: There is actually a couple more possibilities.  I agree vibration is likely the cause, with ceiling fans it usually is the reason, however other things to consider: if the lamp doesn't seat well in the socket, it's possibly for the socket and base to generate extra heat.  Also wattage greater than recommended generates more heat. Both of these can cause premature lamp failure, in any fixture not just ceiling fans.

Comment: If the fan is vibrating noticeably, get it fixed -- balanced.  Don't cure the symptom (i.e. with heavy duty bulbs): cure the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are [industrial duty lamps](http://www.bulbs.com/product/40A-220-220V?cm_mmc=GooglePLA-_-Nonbrand-_-%7Bcampaign%7D-_-shopping&affID=6&adpos=1o6&creative=83499210558&device=c&matchtype=&network=g&gclid=COvQtKSa1cwCFQJsfgod7W4Njg) they are built to take some vibration. We use these in areas that have vibration. They do cost more but hold up better than off the shelf lamps.

Answer (score 1):

You're really better off going with an LED bulb for a couple of reasons.  First, they last 20 years and are immune to vibration. Second, they make less heat, if you're running your fan to cool off.

They are now reasonably priced, and come in any color you want, so you don't need that "blue-ish" color if you don't want it, and they even come in old-timey looking styles.

Do not buy CFLs.  They don't like vibration or running base up, are full of mercury and don't last.